# Best Critical Region for Poisson Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_{10}$ be a random sample from a Poisson distribution with mean $\theta$. Show that the best critical region against the hypothesis $H_0: \theta = 0.1$ and $H_1: \theta = 0.5$ is $C = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)| \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i \geq3\}$.

My problem is getting the sum to be greater than equal to 3. I get that $\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i \geq \frac{4-ln(k)}{ln(5)}$ by the Neyman-Pearson theorem, but I don't understand why this implies this is greater than or equal to 3.

Comment: I believe your inequality should be $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^{10}x_i>\frac{0.4-\ln k}{\ln5}\ $.  You haven't given a value for the required level of significance $\ k\ $, but if you take $\ k=0.05\ $, a very commonly used value, then $\ \frac{0.4-\ln k}{\ln5}\ $ evaluates approximately to $\ 2.1\ $.  But since $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^{10}x_i\ $ must be an integer, $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^{10}x_i\ge2.1\ $ is equivalent to $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^{10}x_i\ge3\ $.

Comment: We are not given a significance level, the next part of the problem ask for us to find the significance level for our critical region $\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i >=3$ and the power of the test when we assume $H_1$ to be true. $k$ is our value for which $L(0.1)/L(0.5) \leq k$ for the Neyman-Pearson Theorem.

Comment: Apologies for confusing the significance level with the bound on the likelihood ratio.  For the fomer, I get $\ \sum_\limits{n=3}^\infty\frac{e^{-1}}{n!}=$$1-2.5e^{-1}\approx0.08\ $ for the critical region $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^{10}x_i\ge3\ $.  As I understand it, the Neyman-Pearson theorem tells you that the likelihood ratio test is the most powerful for any given significance level, so I don't see how it's possible to obtain a critical region at all unless you're given either the required significance level or the required power of the test.

Comment: Or, of course, you're given the value of $\ k\ $.

Comment: We are not given a value of $k$. If that was the case, this would be much more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an outline and some relevant computations from R.

Let $S = \sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i.$ Under $H_0,$ we have $S \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 1)$ and under $H_1$ we have $S \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 1).$

The Neyman-Pearson theorem show that we should reject $H_0$ for large $S.$
Because one would expect larger values of $S$ if $H_1$ is true, it makes
sense that the critical region should be of the form $S \ge c,$ but we need
to do computations involving Poisson distributions in order to know what
significance level $\alpha$ is implied by a specific critical value $c.$
The statement of your problem suggests using $c = 3.$

The significance level is
$$\alpha = P(\mathrm{Rej}\,H_0) | H_0\,\mathrm{True}) = P(S \ge 3|\lambda=1)\\
= 1 - P(S \le 2|\lambda=1) \approx 0.08,$$
which agrees with @lonzaleggiera's second comment. Computation in R, where `ppois` is a Poisson CDF:

```
1 - ppois(2, 1)
[1] 0.0803014
```

Then the power $\pi$ of the test with this specified critical region is as follows:

$$\pi = P(\mathrm{Rej}\,H_0) | H_1\,\mathrm{True}) = P(S \ge 3|\lambda=5)\\
= 1 - P(S \le 2|\lambda=5) \approx 0.875.$$

```
1 - ppois(2, 5)
[1] 0.875348
```

In the figure below the blue bars correspond to the null distribution
$\mathsf{Pois}(1)$ and the brown bars to the alternative distribution
$\mathsf{Pois}(5).$ The critical region is to the right of the dotted vertical
line. The significance level is given by the sum of the heights of the blue bars
in the critical region and the power is given by the sum of the heights of the
brown bars.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
s = 0:12;  pdf.0 = dpois(s, 1);  pdf.1 = dpois(s, 5)
hdr = "Null and Alternative Distn's"
plot(s-.05, pdf.0, type="h", col="blue", lwd=3, ylab="PDF", xlab="s", main=hdr)
 lines(s+.05, pdf.1, type="h", col="brown", lwd=3)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 2.5, lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

Comment: Typo: " ... under $H_1$ we have $S \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = \color{red}1).$"